# Vs Code Intellisense only shows some results after typing two characters

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I try to get intelissense in php language from an object in Vs Code, when I type I only get some results when typing at least two characters.
I don't know why not all results are displayed by default, or just by typing a single character?

See an example bellow when I try to get intelissense for `email`:
[image]

Have you some idea of the problem ?

Thanks